# Remove last character of every nth line in place

Tags: bash, text, awk, sed

I have a file with four repeated lines. I am looking to remove the last character of every fourth line. A description of the file is below.

```
@Header  
DNA Sequence 
+ 
Quality score!
<Pattern of four above lines repeats>
```

I am trying to remove the last character (an exclamation point) from every fourth Quality score line.

```
@Header  
DNA Sequence 
+ 
Quality score
<Pattern of four above lines repeats>
```

I am able to use awk to pull out every fourth line, but **how do I remove the last character in place on every fourth line of the file**?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32555508/how-to-remove-last-character-of-nth-line-linux) operates only on a specific line. Currently my approach is to use awk to pull the Quality score and I can remove the last character with sed.

```
awk 'NR == 4 || NR % 4 == 0'
sed 's/.$//'
```

I am currently not sure how to overwrite the edited Quality scores into the original file. Any thoughts or more concise inplace sed / awk arguments would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post expected output too in your post now./

Comment: Why do you want to remove only the last quality and leave at the same time the last base???

Comment: Hey @RavinderSingh13, thanks for the edits

Comment: Hi @Poshi, great question, my quality scores have an additional Phred character (!) than all my sequences. It took me a bit to figure that out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat file
1!
2!
3!
4!
5!
6!
7!
8!
9!
10!
11!
12!
```

You can use awk:

```
$ awk 'NR%4==0{sub(/!$/,"")}1' file
1!
2!
3!
4
5!
6!
7!
8
9!
10!
11!
12
```

And if you have `gawk` you can change in place:

```
$ gawk -i inplace 'NR%4==0{sub(/!$/,"")}1' file
$ cat file
1!
2!
3!
4
5!
6!
7!
8
9!
10!
11!
12
```

If you only have POSIX awk, you can effectively get an inplace replacement by using a temp file:

```
$ awk 'NR%4==0{sub(/!$/,"")}1' file >tmp_file && mv tmp_file file
```

(Which is what GNU sed or GNU awk or perl or ruby is doing under the covers anyway with 'inplace' replacement...)

Comment: Thanks @dawg, this works in place as well with the sed flag.

Comment: sed is generating the sample input to demonstrate the solution, not solving your problem. `awk 'NR%4==0{sub(/!$/,"")}1'` is the solution to your problem.

Comment: If you have `gawk` you can use `gawk -i inplace` to do inplace replacements.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton, so I would still have to mv the file unless I have gawk to do inplace.

Comment: Right, you need GNU awk for inplace editing with awk just like you need GNU or BSD sed for inplace editing with sed.

Comment: @CodyGlickman remark that inplace in sed and awk is nothing more then a fancy word for "create a new file with a temporary name and then just move it, overwriting the old file.

Answer (score 6):

GNU-sed has an extension that can operate on every n-th line:

```
sed '4~4s/.$//'
```

`m~n` means on the `m`-th line repeated every `n` lines, run the following command.

Comment: ~ is an invalid command code on my Mac's sed. I appreciate the input though, this is beautiful and I will try this later on my linux desktop.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: Thanks @jas, a little homebrew goes a long way

Answer (score 3):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -lpe 'chop if 0 == $. % 4'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints it after processing
- `-l` removes a newline from the input line and adds it back to output
- [chop](http://p3rl.org/chop) removes the last character
- `$.` is a special [perlvar](http://p3rl.org/perlvar) that contains the input line number, `%` is the modulo [operator](http://p3rl.org/perlop)

Comment: Hi @choroba, as someone who typically bemoans perl, this is very concise and readable. Also, it works great.

Comment: @CodyGlickman: Perl can be readable and concise. Unfortunately, many people can't use it that way.

Comment: Readable Perl and Ruby one line answers almost always get my +1

Comment: @choroba, this answer has swayed my misconceptions about perl :)

Comment: And in ruby you can do: `ruby -lpe 'chop if $. % 4==0' file` Both Ruby and Perl support inplace file editing with the addition of `-i ext` to this one line command

Comment: Though not terrible, I'd argue that that code is still not clear so therefore it's brief but not concise. Show `perl -lpe 'chop if 0 == $. % 4'` to some random C programmer and ask them what it does. Now show them `awk 'NR%4==0{sub(/.$/,"")}1' file` which is the equivalent. I'm not saying the awk script is completely clear as it's relying on `1` as shorthand for `{print}` for brevity but I think the average programmer is far more likely to understand the awk script at a glance than they are the perl script.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk 'FNR%4==0{print substr($0,1,length($0)-1);next} 1' Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

This will save the output into Input_file itself(it will create a output directory named `temp_file` and then rename/move `temp_file` to your actual `Input_file`).

Comment: This works! I am guessing I could change the 4 after FNR% if I wanted to operate on different lines too. Thanks again!

Comment: @CodyGlickman, yes `FNR%4==0` means if line number is fully divided by `4` then do this action. Yes you could change it as per your wish too, will add full explanation in few mins too.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'n;n;n;s/.$//' file
```

Or

```
sed 'N;N;N;s/.$//' file
```